# Using Net::SSH with File.exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to check to see if a file exists on another server.

I'm using Net::SSH due to the password needed and using `File.exist?` to check to see if the file exists. When I run the code it returns false, changing `host` to the second server.

I'm guessing Ruby code doesn't work in `do` sessions, or am I doing this wrong?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/scp'

exist = true
host = "msxafs02.usi.net"
port = 22
user = "root"
password = "password"
remote_path_prefix = "/home/appit"
remote_command = "/home/appit/bin/mast/appit_version_control.pl"

Net::SSH.start(host, user, :password=>password, :port=>port) do |session|
        print host + " SSH started \n"
        if File.exist?("/home/appit/bin/mast/appit_version_control.pl")
                host = "msxafs02.usi.net"
                print "file exist on msxafs02 \n"
        else
                host = "mdsxocd5.usi.net"
                print "file doesn not exist on msxafs02 using mdsxocd5 \n"
        end
end

print host + "\n"
```

Comment: Yes, this is not going to work as you expect it. Putting code in a block doesn't magically delegate that code to that block, you need to check if file exists on `session` object somehow.

Comment: SSH isn't going to move that code to the far system and run it, instead the local Ruby is going to process it locally. You can tell SSH to `exec` remote shell commands, which could launch a remote script which happens to be the same expressions you're trying to do in your block. The SSH session could generate that file if you wanted it to, or you could use `scp` or `sftp` or something similar to move that file to a known place on the remote system prior to running.